# Sort by alphabetical order archive.php page

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) :  the_post();
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' ); 
            
    ?>          
                    
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <div class="servicecard">
                  <div class="border icon rounded-circle shadow text-center">
                      
                      <?php if(get_field('add_service_icon')){?>
                      <img src="<?php the_field('add_service_icon'); ?>">
                      <?php } else {?>
                      <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/camera (1).png" class="w-100  rounded">
                      <?php } ?>
                      
                      </div>
                  <h3 class="fw-bold text-theme mb-3 fs-5"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<!--                   <h6 class="mb-3 ">A NEW PARADIGM INONLINE DISPLAY ADVERTISING.</h6> -->
                  <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(),20);?></p>
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="animated bg-black border border-white bounceInUp d-inline-block hvr-bg hvr-text joinbtn mt-2 text-white" style="animation-delay: 0.3s;">Know More</a>
                  
               </div>
            </div>
            
            
        
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?> 
            <h1 class="text-center">Sorry. No Services Found!</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I am using the above code to display my services in archive.php page. Let me know how can I sort those outputs alphabetically. Thanks in advance. I want to pass arguments before the loop.

Comment: Have you tried using the `pre_get_posts` hook to set the `orderby` parameter?